# Десериализация Json в С#

Tags: c#, json, deserialize

От API мне приходит json файл следующего вида:

```
{
  "location": {
    "name": "name",
    "region": "region",
    "country": "Russia",
    "lat": xx.xx,
    "lon": yy.yy,
    "tz_id": "xx/yy",
    "localtime_epoch": 11111111,
    "localtime": "2023-08-18 23:38"
  },
  "current": {
    "last_updated_epoch": 1692390600,
    "last_updated": "2023-08-18 23:30",
    "temp_c": 21.0,
    "is_day": 0,
    "condition": {
      "text": "Ясно",
      "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
      "code": 1003
    },
    "wind_kph": 15.1,
    "wind_degree": 20,
    "wind_dir": "NNE",
    "pressure_mb": 1025.0,
    "pressure_in": 30.27,
    "precip_mm": 0.8,
    "humidity": 78,
    "cloud": 50,
    "feelslike_c": 21.0,
    "vis_km": 10.0,
    "uv": 1.0,
    "gust_kph": 21.6
  }
}
```

Так же у меня есть класс `Weather` со следующими полями:

```
    public string LastUpdate;
    public double TemperatureCelsius; // в json: current -> temp_c
    public double FeelsLikeCelsius;
    public string Discription; // в json: current -> condition -> text
    public double WindSpeed;
    public string WindDirection;
    public double Pressure;
    public double Precipitation;
    public int Humidity;
    public int Cloud;
    public int UvIndex;
    public bool IsDay;
```

Таким образом, просто `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>` не работает. Конечно, я могу десериализовать в словарь с множеством вложенных словарей, но этот вариант не очень читаемый и поэтому отталкивает меня. Как я могу получить данные из вложений файла (например из `current` -> `condition` взять значение `text`) более элегантным способом, при этом не создавая в классе ненужные мне поля?

Comment: создать несколько классов которые повторяют структуру JSON (weather, location ...), и добавить на свойства JsonPropertyName аттрибут

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, так этого и хотелось бы избежать: не вижу смысла плодить классы с данными, которые мне не нужны.

Comment: @LightChimera то что вы показали в ответе, работает раз 10 медленнее, чем если бы были классы. Да ещё и на базе хоть и крутой, но древней библиотеки. Вам не хотелось бы избежать подключения лишних NuGet пакетов к проекту? В модели данных (классе) не обязательно описывать все поля, добавьте туда только нужные. И в модели данных лучше использовать свойства а не поля.

Comment: А не работает, потому что в вашем классе `Weather` должно быть всего два свойства - `location` и `current`, понимаете намёк?

Comment: @LightChimera Обновил свой ответ, теперь он содержит решение для System.Text.Json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Если проблема в привязки определённых полей объекта к определённым полям json:

В случае, если вы хотите вместо простого имени поля указать путь до этого самого поля, то это решение для вас:

### Решение для System.Text.Json:

Я долго думал и всё же сделал довольно простое решение для стандартной библиотеки:

```cs
public class PathJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : new()
{
    // Этот метод упрощает создание настроек
    public static T? Deserialize(string json, JsonNamingPolicy? namingPolicy = null) 
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.PropertyNamingPolicy = namingPolicy;
        options.Converters.Add(new PathJsonConverter<T>());
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, options);
    }

    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonObject = JsonNode.Parse(ref reader);
        
        T? result = new T();

        foreach (var property in typeToConvert.GetProperties())
        {
            JsonNode? currentNode = jsonObject;
            var attr = property.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>();
            if (attr == null)
                currentNode = currentNode?[options.PropertyNamingPolicy?.ConvertName(property.Name) ?? property.Name];
            else
                foreach (var path in attr.Name.Split('.'))
                    currentNode = currentNode?[path];

            if (currentNode != null)
                property.SetValue(result, getObject(currentNode));
        }

        return result;
    }
    object? getObject(JsonNode node) => node.GetValue<JsonElement>().ValueKind switch
    {
        JsonValueKind.Null => null,
        JsonValueKind.Undefined => null,
        JsonValueKind.String => node.GetValue<string>(),
        JsonValueKind.Array => node.GetValue<JsonArray>(),
        JsonValueKind.Object => node.GetValue<JsonObject>(),
        JsonValueKind.Number => node.AsValue().TryGetValue(out int val) ? (object)val : (node.AsValue().TryGetValue(out float fval) ? (object)fval : (object)node.GetValue<double>()),
        JsonValueKind.False => false,
        JsonValueKind.True => true,
        _ => null
    };

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Данный способ позволяет указывать json путь в JsonPropertyName, а так же позволяет использовать имя поля когда путь не указан и поддерживает кастомный `PropertyNamingPolicy` (из решения ниже)

Использование:

```
class Model
{
    [JsonPropertyName("values.val")]
    public int ValuesVal { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("single")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public string? OtherValue { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{""values"":{""val"":4}, ""single"": 2, ""other_value"": ""Here is other value""}";

// SnakeCaseNamingPolicy взят из решения  
// проблемы с политикой наименования ниже
// Данный параметр не обязателен, и нужен только
// для преобразования из "OtherValue" в "other_value"
Model? model = PathJsonConverter<Model>.Deserialize(json, new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy());

Console.WriteLine($"{model?.Value}, {model?.ValuesVal}, {model?.OtherValue}");
```

### Решение для Newtonsoft.Json:

Я рекомендую вам использовать Newtonsoft.Json, так как он представляет очень мощный функционал для работы с json и лучше кастомизируется.

```cs
class JsonPathConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jsonObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        object targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) ?? throw new JsonException($"Can't create instance of {objectType}");

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objectType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute? att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            string jsonPath = att?.PropertyName ?? prop.Name;
            JToken? token = jsonObj.SelectToken(jsonPath);

            if ((token?.Type ?? JTokenType.Null) != JTokenType.Null)
            {
                object? value = token?.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer);
                prop.SetValue(targetObj, value, null);
            }
        }
        return targetObj;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Использование:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
class TestClass
{
    [JsonProperty("values.some_value")]
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

TestClass testClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(@"{""values"": {""some_value"": 5}}");

Console.WriteLine(testClass.SomeValue)
```

## Если проблема в политики наименования:

Если же проблема в соответствии способов наименования (типо `ObjectName` и `object_name`), то вам сюда

### Решение для System.Net.Json:

```cs
public class SnakeCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name) => 
        string.Concat(name.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString())).ToLower();
}
```

Использование:

```cs
TestObject testObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestObject>(
    "{\"int_value\": 5}", 
    new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy()
    }
);
Console.WriteLine(testObject.IntValue);
```

### Решение для Newtonsoft.Json:

Решение для данной задачи уже была встроена в библиотеку:

```cs
TestObject testObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(
    "{\"int_value\": 5}",
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() }
    }
);
Console.WriteLine(testObject.IntValue);
```

Comment: Надеюсь я не опоздал)

Comment: А при чем тут именование, и попытка получения значения из вложенного объекта, без создания класса под этот объект?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вопрос плохо прописан, да и я внимательно не прочитал) Думал проблема в разной политики наименования) Сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Обновил свой ответ

Comment: Ахаха `данной фичи нет в стандартной библиотеки, то я рекомендую вам использовать Newtonsoft.Json`, ух сейчас прибегут сторонники и будут доказывать, что "System.Text.Json всемогущий")) (ух как я с ним намучался...). Он кстати там есть (ну, способ решения), но делается сложнее. Но да ладно, шутки шутками, но хоть теперь ответ соответствует действительности, и на том спасибо. Минус если что не мой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я не нашёл. Перерыл весь интернет, потому что стыдно стало, что даже нормально на вопрос ответить не смог) Пытался реализовать через конверторы и другие методы... Может дадите наводку?

Comment: Да все также, через конвертор, но только не универсальный (хотя его попробовать тоже можно собрать), а что-то вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402592/6808809), тут правда JSON строку делают, но по аналогии вытянуть нужный объект без труда можно. Ну или можно пойти другим путем, конструктор, [например так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416875/6808809), даже проще получается объект, меньше кода) Кстати, указывайте ссылки, от куда взяли код, а то как-то не оч красивы выглядит... В том вопросе мне больше [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932675/6808809) вариант понравился.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Интересное решение, я как то и забыл, что можно добавлять и читать свои атрибуты, а в JsonPropertyName передать что угодно нельзя, иначе он будет просто проигнорирован... Теперь хочу реализовать это через свои аттрибуты) Да и про переопределение конвертора тоже что то не подумал) Обновлю вопрос

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Во, зацени моё решение) Как по мне получилось неплохо)

Comment: Вполне. Из замечаний 1. Методы с большой буквы пишутся (`getObject`), и его можно сделать статичным. 2. Не забывайте ставить модификатор доступа, даже если метод приватный, это хороший тон. 3. Имена более осмысленные давайте, а то `fval` я лично не сразу понял что это, пока не прочитал код... 4. Всякие `(object)val` - лишняя конвертация, можно убрать. 5. `foreach` можно в LINQ превратить `attr.Name.Split('.').Aggregate(currentNode, (current, path) => current?[path]);`, тогда `if` можно переделать в простое `??` условие. 6. Не уверен, что `Deserialize` уместен в конверторе, не его задача.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А вот с (object)val проблемка вышла) Вначале я был без него, но тогда switch автоматически определял тип как JsonElement (потому что видимо все примитивные типы можно преобразовать к этому типу) Метод же я случайно написал с маленькой буквы (потому что приватные свойства тоже с маленькой), на счёт модификаторов доступа хз, тут уже вкусовщина, а за остальные замечания спасибо!

Comment: Может быть можно как то указать возвращаемый тип для switch

Comment: Смысл, если `property.SetValue(...)` принимает только `object`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Объясните это siwtch) Даже не смотря на то, что метод возвращает object? switch всё равно самостоятельно определяет свой тип, который наиболее *дочерний* для всех входящих в него типов. Можете проверить и убрать (object) - код вызовет ошибку

Comment: Ага, это я что-то не проверил.  Тут дело не в `switch`, а в конструкции типа `true ? 1 : 2`, где выходным типом будет не то, что ожидается, в вашем коде им будет скорей всего последний `double`, ну а после этого `SetValue()` из-за несоответствия типов выдаст ошибку, это да. Ну, тогда убрать все `(object)` кроме последнего, правда это костыль, мне кажется этой конвертации можно избежать, но как, пока не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за такой развернутый ответ. Хотя это немного не то, что было нужно мне, но я уверен, что в будущем Ваш ответ многим поможет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хотелось бы что бы можно было явно задать возвращаемый тип для switch... Напишу потом запрос на гитхабе, может быть одобряд синтаксис типа `(T)swith`

Comment: @LightChimera Жаль что не смог помочь) Однако хотелось узнать, чем моё решение не устроило и в чём был настоящий вопрос
Вроде как он как раз позволяет парсить json разной глубины без создания новых объектов (указывая путь в аттрибуте для нужного поля, например "current.condition.text", что соответствует вопросу)

Answer (score -1):

Нашел возможное решение - использовать тип `dynamic`. Да, им лучше не злоупотреблять, так как сложнее отлавливать состояния, но конкретно в моем случае решение неплохое.

```
        dynamic weatherData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
        weatherData = weatherData["current"];

        LastUpdate = weatherData["last_updated"];
        TemperatureCelsius = weatherData["temp_c"];
        FeelsLikeCelsius = weatherData["feelslike_c"];
        Discription = weatherData["condition"]["text"];
        WindSpeed = weatherData["wind_kph"];
        WindDirection = weatherData["wind_dir"];
        Pressure = weatherData["pressure_mb"];
        Precipitation = weatherData["precip_mm"];
        Humidity = weatherData["humidity"];
        Cloud = weatherData["cloud"];
        UvIndex = weatherData["uv"];
        IsDay = weatherData["is_day"];
```

Изменено: в результате я отказался от такого решения и, как было предложено в комментариях, создал несколько вспомогательных классов.

Comment: Это плохое решение. В комментариях хорошее предлагают. Ещё Newtonsoft.Json устарел много лет назад. Все используют System.Text.Json. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to